# replace text from dictionary priority to longer string

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am trying to write a program to replace text in a file using a dictionary.

```
def preprocess(text, preprocessing_dict):
    rc = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, preprocessing_dict)))
    def translate(match):
     return preprocessing_dict[match.group(0)]
    return rc.sub(translate, text)
```

I want to replace the longer strings first before going for substrings. In most instances, the above code snippet seems to do the job. For example,

```
preprocessing_dict = { 'ka': 'k', 'ka+i': '<k*' }
```

Any instance of `ka+i` is replaced by `<k*` and not `k+i`.

But in the longer version of the dictionary (206 key:value pairs read from a text file), `'na': 'n', 'na+i': '<n*'` any instance of `na+i` is replaced by `n+i`. But `ka+i` still works fine.

I hope you can point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered, you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pull the keys out in sorted order first.

```
keys = sorted(preprocessing_dict.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just for the reference of someone (me?) who might have a similar question in the future. The following changes work : `def preprocess(text, preprocessing_dict, sorted_keys): ...map(re.escape, sorted_keys)` and `sorted_keys = sorted(preprocessing_dict.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)`